# How to make each key of an object as a variable with the same name as the key in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript object like this:

```
var obj1={a:1,b:2,c:3}
```

From this i need to extract each key as a variable like this:

```
    var a=1
    var b=2
    var c=3
```

How can this be done?

Comment: `const { a, b, c } = obj1;`

Comment: I am just curious, but what is the purpose of wanting to do that?

Comment: i mean you could use `eval("var " + key + " = " + value + ";")` though i really see no point in it.

Comment: @Dellirium Your method also works in solving my problem. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a great looking solution (this *isn't* the sort of thing you should be doing - better to work with just the initial object), but you could assign all properties of `obj1` to the window object, allowing you to reference them standalone, without having to know the keys beforehand:

```js
var obj1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
};
Object.assign(window, obj1);
console.log(c);
```

Comment: @AkshayBharadwaj keep in mind that he said you shound not be doing it. It is not good for multiple reasons and in practicality not very useful to do so.

Answer (score 3):

It can be done using ES6 destructuring, you can explode all the object's properties and assign it in a variable the same as the property's name

```
var {a,b,c} = obj1;

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
console.log(c);
```

Comment: This was just a sample object. I have an object having 100 keys . Doing this method will not be feasible. i need to be able to do this iteratively

Answer (score -1):

Try with:

```js
var obj1={a:1,b:2,c:3}

let keys = Object.keys(obj1)
keys.forEach(key => {
let value = obj1[key.toString()];
  console.log(key); // Use Key
  console.log(value) // Use Value
})
```